# App Engine Map Reduce Exception On Controller Callback

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

When running a Map Reduce job on our app engine Java instance it stalls after a while and I get an exception that the request is too large. Its unclear from the exception how to resolve this since the is happening in the shuffle stage which is supposed to be seamless.

I understand the limits on entity sizes, timeouts etc. but I'm not sure where to indicate this to the API?

I used code quite similar to the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava), that just counts different property attributes and left the servlet almost the same.

This is what I'm getting:

```
2012-12-02 13:18:53.632 /mapreduce/controllerCallback 500 535ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
0.1.0.2 - - [02/Dec/2012:03:18:53 -0800] "POST /mapreduce/controllerCallback HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://xxx/mapreduce/controllerCallback" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxx.com" ms=535 cpu_ms=288 queue_name=default task_name=16764257756372630651 instance=00c61b117cc2653091fefc2f9b795b790f1a
I 2012-12-02 13:18:53.203
com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.impl.shardedjob.ShardedJobRunner pollTaskStates: Polling task states for job 002b0ae1-643b-420d-b3cd-20f03cc054ff-reduce, sequence number 166
W 2012-12-02 13:18:53.630
/mapreduce/controllerCallback
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:494)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:392)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:781)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:823)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:808)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:898)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:803)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1063)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:911)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2267)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2068)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:143)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3129)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:599)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:424)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:265)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:217)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:81)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:136)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1855)
C 2012-12-02 13:18:53.631
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:494)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:392)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:781)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:823)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:808)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:898)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:803)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1063)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:911)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2267)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2068)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:143)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3129)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:599)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:424)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:265)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:217)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:81)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:136)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1855)
```

I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=94) but I'm not using any entities, I'm guessing the entity is being created to store the data but since I'm not sure where to define how much I should write to it?

Answer (score 4):

I get the same exception when running a Map Reduce.
The problem was that the Map Reduce contains a lot of metadata, that was generated during the job, after that the data is save as a single entity in the datastore.
When the entity becomes bigger than allowed, then an exception is throw and the Map Reduce stops.

My problem was that I write lots of logs like

```
context.getCounter("some log message", "value");
```

in the body of the Map Reduce.
The solution was to reduce logs size and count.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that, the question is how to avoid/fix that? Did you manage to do so?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice you updated since it didn't popup (it would help adding a comment so I would get the notification). I'll try reducing the number of strings I emit but I'm not sure how practical this is for my use cases.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of entities you can write in one call is 500 and at present, entities can be at most 1 MB in size. This is described here:

[Quotas_and_Limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits)

So you're trying to store too much data in your entities and hence this exception is thrown. 
Following are some workarounds you can try:

- split your data into multiple entities of less than 1 MB chunks(Don't know your exact use case to comment specifically)
- use [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for especially large files.

Comment: That's why I wrote: "I understand the limits on entity sizes, timeouts etc.". The question is how to get the App Engine Map reduce to not violate that. It uses the datastore and not S3.

Comment: Can you control the amount of input you are sending to each mapper? Basically, in order to control the amount of output per reducer, in that way you may perhaps control the put data size.

Comment: There isn't that much there and its not even the largest entity set we have.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same issue, and traced it to my Mapper class.  That class's member data gets serialized to/form the datastore between slices (I think), and I had a large amount of that data, which exceeded 1MB.  It was not related to any explicit calls to the datastore that my class was making.

Comment: Thanks I figured that out myself. The question is how do I control the amount of data? I don't have that much output from the mapper and even if I reduce the amount I'll run into the same issue as my data set (which is now 10's of millions of entries) grows

Comment: In my case the issue was not related to my Mapper's output.  I was keeping a HashMap in memory, as an optimization to the datastore.  That grew too large.  So I moved the optimization to memcache.